# IOS Crashed - Crash EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) - bug 109

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports

app crashed :( please help me.. In this regard failed. I can't find the error? The application works connect to iTunesConnect but it give error.

Can anyone tell what the problem is based on the crash report below?

```
share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109",
Incident Identifier: 59F03611-CFDC-40B6-A4EA-8ECA5387EE04
CrashReporter Key:   90aaa276000e47bda1a19fc4f736b7a427324e2e
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             YESAPP [1114]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5D2C85E0-35E5-4CEE-BC7F-C63F71311BFB/YESAPP.app/YESAPP
Identifier:          com.ysn.YESAPPapp
Version:             2.1.5 (2.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.ysn.YESAPPapp [704]


Date/Time:           2016-10-11 11:18:19.0227 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-10-11 11:18:18.7907 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1830f41c0 0x181b2c55c 0x182fd3ad4 0x10009b6f0 0x188fa842c 0x1891b8b70 0x1891be8e0 0x1891d3080 0x1891bb8c4 0x184c958bc 0x184c95728 0x184c95ad0 0x1830a2278 0x1830a1bc0 0x18309f7c0 0x182fce048 0x188fa15dc 0x188f9c360 0x10009ccbc 0x181fb05b8)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001820c2014 0x1820a3000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182189460 0x182184000 + 21600
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001820363f4 0x181fd3000 + 406516
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181b012d4 0x181b00000 + 4820
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181b1ecc0 0x181b00000 + 126144
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181b2c844 0x181b24000 + 34884
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181b1b66c 0x181b00000 + 112236
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181b1b234 0x181b00000 + 111156
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181b2c71c 0x181b24000 + 34588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182fce0bc 0x182fc5000 + 37052
10  UIKit                           0x0000000188fa15dc 0x188f26000 + 505308
11  UIKit                           0x0000000188f9c360 0x188f26000 + 484192
12  YESAPP                          0x000000010009ccbc 0x10008c000 + 68796
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000181fb05b8 0x181fac000 + 17848

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182184db0 0x182184000 + 3504

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182184db0 0x182184000 + 3504

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182184db0 0x182184000 + 3504

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001820c2a88 0x1820a3000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018218536c 0x182184000 + 4972
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182184db4 0x182184000 + 3508

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001820a416c 0x1820a3000 + 4460
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001820a3fdc 0x1820a3000 + 4060
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001830a1cec 0x182fc5000 + 904428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018309f908 0x182fc5000 + 895240
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182fce048 0x182fc5000 + 36936
5   Foundation                      0x0000000183adcb1c 0x183ad0000 + 51996
6   Foundation                      0x0000000183afd60c 0x183ad0000 + 185868
7   UIKit                           0x0000000189916c7c 0x188f26000 + 10423420
8   Foundation                      0x0000000183bda50c 0x183ad0000 + 1090828
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182187860 0x182184000 + 14432
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182187770 0x182184000 + 14192
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182184dbc 0x182184000 + 3516

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001700f3d37
    x4: 0x0000000181b1fbc3   x5: 0x000000016fd73590   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000000000000b  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x000000018204d792  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000030000000300  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001a771ac40  x21: 0x000000016fd73590  x22: 0x00000001a7721bb8  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x000000017001e370  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016fd73be0   fp: 0x000000016fd734f0   lr: 0x0000000182189460
    sp: 0x000000016fd734d0   pc: 0x00000001820c2014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: how to ask? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need resimbolicate this crash log

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your app you use abort() function, maybe it's in coredata. App crashes because abort() function called.

Answer (score 1):

In my case when i got this crash it was due to assigning a NSString to an NSNumber, it wa difficult for me to track it down because this was only happpening when users clicked a section that was not really necessary for completing th epimary action of that screen. I had to run the app on xcode then look at the console log when crash happens